# sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher in sklearn 0.22

Tags: python, hash, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I just updated to sklearn 0.22. My code used to work in the previous version, but now it gives an error:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher
a = FeatureHasher(n_features = 5, input_type = 'string')
```

Now it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in hasher_partner = FeatureHasher()

File "C:\Users\77797\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\hashing.py", line 89, in init

File "C:\Users\77797\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\hashing.py", line 100, in _validate_params

NameError: name 'numbers' is not defined
```

Any solutions?
Thanks!

Comment: `numbers` is a standard library package. try `import numbers` in your python repl

Comment: @abhilb Thanks! It's strange that when I was using ```sklearn``` I didn't need to import it!

Answer (score 0):

The package that you are using is not `scikit-learn` 0.22. In the traceback, the module imported is `hashing.py` and has been renamed `_hashing.py` in 0.22

Coudl you make sure that you have the good version of scikit-learn `import sklearn; sklearn.__version__`. If you have the version 0.22, try to reinstall the package with conda: `conda install scikit-learn --force-reinstall`.